# how can i get file from smb file server at my app iOS

Tags: ios, bonjour, samba, smb, afp

I am developing an app,I want to get file from shared folder,I used bonjour to find file server around me and I get the ip address and server type;
now I want to get the shared file from these file server?how can I get these? I google it and I know to get this file I have to implement something like afp or smb ,then I can get file.
but can somebody tell me exactly what should I do? and can somebody give me demo? I searched a smb demo "tango" at github,but its doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, 'bonjour', 'mDNS' or whatever else you want to call it assists *purely* with discovery, which you can do easily enough in iOS / OS X, assuming the SMB server you want is advertising itself as a service of type `_smb._.tcp.`. See [NSNetServiceBrowser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetServiceBrowser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and related classes on how to do that.

The hard bit, AFAIK, is actually connecting to said server and retrieving the file. The best resource I can point to is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032314/smb-samba-support-on-ios) here, and perhaps [this client library](https://github.com/kolyvan/kxsmb) (although I've never used it personally).

Hope this helps.