# How to download a file over smb in Swift (tvOS)

Tags: swift, networking, tvos, smb

How to download a file over smb in Swift (tvOS)?
NetFS and Cooca are not available for tvOS and when I'm using URLSession dataTask "smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/share/test.txt" Swift tells me that smb is not a valid url.

Is there any solution to download a file over smb for tvOS?

Tried it with this code:

```
 let url = self.smbManager.getFullUrl(fileName: self.file.name)
 let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(url: url!)
 let session = URLSession.shared
 session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
     print(data)
 }.resume()
```

Error is:
finished with error [-1002] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/share/test.txt, NSErrorFailingURLKey=smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/share/test.txt, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask .<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask .<1>, NSUnderlyingError=0x2813a7c60 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}}

Thanks.

Comment: There have already been some research about using samba in iOS :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032314/smb-samba-support-on-ios

Comment: Yeah, but iOS do have NetFS what tvOS do not have and so on...

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for smb:**

```
let url = NSURL(string: "smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/share/test.txt")
let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()   
session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in                                  print("Response")    
let reply = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) 

print(reply)
    
}
```

`URLSession` is designed to make network transfers as easy as possible, and a great example of that is its `downloadTask() method. This fetches the contents of a URL you specify, saves it to a local file, then calls a completion handler so you can manipulate the file – all in one.

To demonstrate this, here’s some code to download the source code to the apple.com homepage:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!

let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { localURL, urlResponse, error in
    if let localURL = localURL {
        if let string = try? String(contentsOf: localURL) {
            print(string)
        }
    }
}

task.resume()
```

There are a few important things to note in there:

1. Your completion handler gets called with a local URL, which is where the data was saved locally. This is optional, so you need to unwrap it carefully.
2. If something went wrong – e.g. if the network was down – then you’ll
   get an error passed to you explaining what happened.
3. When you have created your download task you should call `resume()`
   on it to make it happen.
4. You don’t need to worry about storing the download task somewhere
   while it happens – it’s being tracked by the shared `URLSession` on
   your behalf.

Comment: And this solution has been tested with a smb:// link?

Comment: I tried this already with a smb link, but i get an "unsupported url" error

Comment: check my Solution for smb

Comment: Still getting an unsupported url error. Updated my question with error and code