# ipad: read file which is on a shared network drive

Tags: ios, networking, shared, nsurlrequest, drive

I'm writing an iPad App, which downloads Files from a DMS (over https). This works fine. But now I need to download large video files from a shared network drive over a vpn connection.

When I create an NSURL object with

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"\\\\filer1\shareName\myFoler\movie.mp4" isDirectory:NO];
```

and a NSURLRequest with

```
[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

it results in the following URL:

```
file://localhost/%5C%5Cfiler1%5CshareName%5CmyFolder%5Cmovie.mp4
```

Why does it add "localhost" before my \filer1?

And how can i download Files from a shared network drive?

Thank you for your help!
cheers, mike

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does iOS support file operations via SMB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660795/does-ios-support-file-operations-via-smb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ios has no support for direct access for files on windows network shares.

see also this question: [SMB/samba support on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032314/smb-samba-support-on-ios) or [Does iOS support file operations via SMB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660795/does-ios-support-file-operations-via-smb?lq=1)